# Determine if the following is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

$L: R^3 \rightarrow R^3,L(x)=(x_1,0,0)$

Linear Transfromations $V$ to $W$

**Using this theorem**

If L is a linear transformation mapping a vector space $V$ into a vector space W, then

$(I) L(0V ) = 0W (\text{where 0V and 0W are the zero vectors in V and W, respectively)}. \\ (II) \text{if v1, . . . , vn are elements of V and α1, . . . , αn are scalars, then }
L(α1v1 + α2v2 +· · ·+αnvn) = α1L(v1) + α2L(v2)+· · ·+αnL(vn) \\(III) L(−v) = −L(v) \text{ for all } v ∈ V.  $

$(I) L(x+y) = L(x_1,x_2,x_3)+(y_1,y_2,y_3)=L(x_!+y_1,x_2+y_2,x_3+y_3)= \\(x_1+y_1,0,0)=(x_1,0,0)+(y_!,0,0)=L(x)+L(y).\\(II) L( \alpha)=L(\alpha(x_1,x_2,x_3))=L(\alpha x_1,\alpha x_2,\alpha x_3)=(\alpha x_1,0,0)=\alpha(x_1,0,0)=\alpha L(x)$

How does one prove the third condition?

Comment: The I and II in your answers are enough.  You can use them to prove the I,II,III in your questions.

Comment: But how does one show that it fulfills the third condition?

Comment: "**If** $L$ is a linear transformation, **then** (everything you can think of)" is obviously not the thing you need to use. Per se, that lemma is perfectly consistent with the existence of a non-linear function which satisfies "(everything you can think of)". Since you want to **prove** linearity, you need a lemma that is written in the form "**If** a function satisfies these properties, **then** it is linear".

Comment: @Michael Why is it enough for I and II enough to show III?

Comment: The I and II of your answers are not the I and II of your question.  Put alpha=-1 into the II of your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear transformation if, for $\mathbf{v_1} = (x_1, y_1, z_1) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $\mathbf{v_2} = (x_2, y_2, v_2) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and $k \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$
L(k\mathbf{v_1} + \mathbf{v_2}) = kL(\mathbf{v_1}) + L(\mathbf{v_2}).
$$

To show this, just substitute $\mathbf{v_1}$ and $\mathbf{v_2}$ for their respective 3-tuples and show the LHS is equal to the RHS.

$$
\begin{align*}
L(k\mathbf{v_1} + \mathbf{v_2}) &= L(k(x_1, y_1, z_1) + (x_2, y_2, z_2))\\
&= L((kx_1 + x_2, ky_1 + y_2, kz_1 + z_2))\\
&= (kx_1 + x_2, 0, 0)\\
&= k (x_1, 0, 0) + (x_2, 0, 0)\\
&= k L(\mathbf{v_1}) + L(\mathbf{v_2})\\
&= LHS.
\end{align*}
$$